# Include null values within a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-date-functions

Im trying to filter out the data between the date range, which also includes null values,
eg: start_date = 18/01/2013 and end_date = 20/01/2013

In some data in the database the start_date is 19/01/2013 and end_date = null; I need to include this particular value as well,
Here's the query I've tried so far

```
SELECT T1.START_DATE,
       T1.END_DATE
FROM   myTable T1
WHERE  to_date(T1.START_DATE, 'DD/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') >= to_date('01/01/2013 10:58:58', 'DD/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
       AND to_date(T1.END_DATE, 'DD/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') <= to_date(IS NULL('21/01/2013 10:58:58', 0), 'DD/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
```

I still can't find the results with null values, Please let me know how will i go about solving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: `TO_DATE()` isn't part of SQL Server, so far as I'm aware. Your sample code and your tags don't match, but I'm not sure in what direction it needs correcting.

Comment: I can't find any reference to `to_date()` in MSDN either, but is the query currently returning the records where the END_DATE IS NOT NULL?

Comment: In a comment to a deleted answer, you said the version is `1.5.5`. That's *not* a SQL Server version number. Either it's the version number of a non-standard client tool that you're using to access SQL Server, or (more likely) you're not using SQL Server. If that's the case, please delete the `sql-server` tag and add a tag that matches the database system you *are* using.

Comment: I think this question needs some editing e.g. correct tags;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely familiar with SQL server, but it doesn't look like `to_date()` is a SQL Server function anyways. I found some reference of it in the [Oracle Database docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions203.htm), so maybe you mean Oracle SQL. try this:

```
SELECT
    T1.START_DATE,
    T1.END_DATE
FROM myTable T1
WHERE 
    to_date(T1.START_DATE,'DD/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') >= to_date('01/01/2013 10:58:58','DD/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
    AND (
        to_date(T1.END_DATE,'DD/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') <= to_date('21/01/2013 10:58:58', 'DD/MM/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
        OR T1.END_DATE IS NULL
    );
```